# How much maximum time i can keep django server running

Tags: django, linux

I run django server using

```
/opt/python27/bin/python manage.py runserver
```

But the command prompt says

```
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I want to know that can i keep it running all the time. Anything wrong with that??.
I was thinking of running in background and then do my usual stuff

Comment: If you start a task from the commandline you can (nearly) always interrupt it with Ctr-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it all the time. You can further append a "&" at the end of the command so to puts the process in the background.
Thus use this instead:

```
/opt/python27/bin/python manage.py runserver &
```

Comment: Yes.  But this is a terrible, terrible way to run a server.  Use Apache and `mod_wsgi`.  Don't think of this as anything but a way to test something quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can keep it running all the time. Don't run it as a foreground process in the terminal, run as a background process.